# How to build a .net5 project with .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to build the same project with 2 different framework.

If relevant, the why : Because I need my project to be used as a reference in a .netcore project and a .netframework project, it has to be compatible with both to avoid duplicating the code.

I thought having build configurations would be the way to go, but the configuration manager makes an error stating the configuration is wrong when adding the framework build configuration.

My csproj looks like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">netcore</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">netframework</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
</Project>
```

But it's not working and I'm confused at to why or what the next step can be.

Any clue?

Comment: Any reason you're not just using multiple target frameworks in a single build configuration? `<TargetFrameworks>net5.0;net451</TargetFrameworks>`

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using EntityFramework in that project, and I need to target 4.5.1 which leads to an error (NU1202 not compatible) at build time

Comment: The element I showed *does* target .NET 4.5.1. That's what `net451` means.

Answer (score 3):

Your csproj looks really confused. It's not clear why `Configuration`, which is normally `Debug` or `Release`, has a `netcore` or `netframework` option, for example.

If you want to build for multiple target frameworks, use a single `TargetFrameworks` element, e.g.

```
<TargetFrameworks>net5.0;net451</TargetFrameworks>
```

If you use `TargetFrameworks`, do not also use `TargetFramework`.

Comment: Visual Studio tends to insert similar conditions when using the Project Properties editor and changing the configuration to "All Configurations".

Answer (score 1):

You can use .NET Standard project. And have reference to it from both of the projects mentioned above. You can find more info here: [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

Quote from Microsoft themselves:

> We recommend you target .NET Standard 2.0, unless you need to support an earlier version. Most general-purpose libraries should not need APIs outside of .NET Standard 2.0. .NET Standard 2.0 is supported by all modern platforms and is the recommended way to support multiple platforms with one target.

Comment: While targeting .NET Standard is an *option*, I wouldn't say they *need* to do it. Targeting `net5.0;net451` should work fine.

Comment: I'm currently testing that approach, I actually did not know that .netstandard was "a mix of .netcore and .netframework". It's providing a little amount of errors that shouldn't be hard to fix, hopefully it'll work :) Keeping the post up to date once I'm done.

Comment: @GilSand Yeah, that should work :) As others have mentioned, using target framework should give positive result as well.